Convert a list of strings of the form {{2 "x" +"y"->4 "x" + 5"y"},{5 "x" ->7"y"}, ...}, to {{"2 x +y"->"4 x +5 y"},{"5 x" ->"7 y"},...}
Convert a list of strings of the form
{{2 "x" +"y"->4 "x" + 5"y"},{5 "x" ->7"y"}, ...}

to
{{"2 x +y"->"4 x +5 y"},{"5 x" ->"7 y"},...}

This maybe a necessary step for the more difficult question Draw a graph on vertices inputted as "A"+ 2 "B", 3"A" + 4"B", etc (the input form is imposed) in Euclidean space, with A->(1,0), B->(0,1)

{{2 "x" + "y" -> 4 "x" + 5 "y"}, {5 "x" -> 7 "y"}};
Map[ToString, %, {3}]


{{"2 x + y" -> "4 x + 5 y"}, {"5 x" -> "7 y"}}


I tried a pure function convEdg[expr_List]:=Map[ToString, #, {3}]&;RN={0 -> "A", "A" -> 2 "A" + "B", 2 "A" + "B" -> 0,
3 "A" + "B" -> 2 "A" + "B", 3 "A" + "B" -> 4 "A" + 2 "B" -> 4 "A",
4 "A" -> 4 "A" + 2 "B", 2 "B" -> 2 "A" + 3 "B",
2 "A" + 3 "B" -> 2 "B"};convEdg[RN]  and it didn't work

@florin  your RN in the example you posted in the comment has different levels than the code you posted in your question, that is why it does not work.   Your question uses list of lists. Your RN has only one list.

@florin Try # /. r_Rule :> ToString /@ r & for nesting-independence.

Thanks! One more question: how to convert either my initial input RN={"B" -> "A", 2 "A" +"B"->"A"+ 2 "B"}, or the new one {"B" -> "A", "2 A + B" -> "A + 2 B"} into the following (sources, products) representation of the three "reactions" by two matrices:S={{0,2},{1,1}} and P={{1,1},{0,2}} (these are the coefficients on the left and right of the reactions) ?

@Florin tr = Transpose[List @@@ {"B" -> "A", 2 "A" + "B" -> "A" + 2 "B"}]; Coefficient[#, "A"] & /@ tr; Coefficient[#, "B"] & /@ tr
